# How to open third party application from PowerApps?

Tags: ios, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I want to open "**nfc-qr-code-docs-for-iphone**" IOS application from PowerApp application.

I found one youtube video regarding it.[Youtube Link of tutorial](https://youtu.be/3Puf3Ki8wbk)

I have tried below code for launching application from PowerApps.

> Launch("nfc-qr-code-docs-for-iphone:///");
>
> Launch("Open=nfc-qr-code-docs-for-iphone");

I don't know why but I'm still not able to open that application.
SMS app and other IOS applications are opening good (built in application) but not this third party application.

For shortcut URL schemes I have referred to this article: [ARTICLE](https://github.com/organicaudio/useful-code-snippets/blob/main/docs/ios/Reference:%20iOS%20App%20URL%20Scheme%20Names%20&%20Paths%20for%20Shortcuts.md)

Is there something that I'm missing or is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: You can only open other application if that particular "scheme"(URLTypes) is handled by that application. like "sms://" opens "Messages" app because "sms://" is added as URLTypes in that application. In your case you should be able to open "nfc-qr-code-docs-for-iphone://" only if that has been handled by that application.

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati How do I know that 'nfc-qr-code-docs-for-iphone' has handled URL scheme or not ?

Comment: I contacted to the developer organization via email . And they responded with answer which is "nfcforiphone://" for above mentioned application.
I still don't know weather there is some way to know the shortcut URL scheme for any application but I got one from developer themselves.

Comment: you won't know custom url scheme for any third party library may be because it can breach security and can steal information from app.

Comment: So I guess we have to contact the developer personally for that.@SaurabhPrajapati